# Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $0 < a < b$. Discuss the convergence of the sequence $x_n:=(a^n+b^n)^{1/n}$ i need steps how to do that

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $0 < a < b$. Discuss the convergence of the sequence
$x_n:=(a^n+b^n)^{1/n}$

my approach to this question is:

while $n \rightarrow\infty$, $1/n \rightarrow 0$,
then $x_n\rightarrow1$ for all $a,\,b \in\mathbb{R}$.
now, by definition:
$$\begin{align}
|x_n-a|&<\varepsilon\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This has been asked and answered repeatedly, you can find many similar or identical questions on this site with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%20%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%20(a%5En%20%2B%20b%5En)%5E%7B1%2Fn%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: Can't separate limits that way.  Consider $\lim_{n\to 0} \frac {2n}{n}$  As $2n\to 0$ that should be $\lim_{n\to 0}\frac {2n}n = \lim_{n\to 0} \frac 0n=\lim 0 = 0$.  Or is that $\frac 1n \to \infty$ and $2n > 0$ so $\infty \cdot 2n = \infty$ so $\lim_{n\to 0}\frac{2n}n = \lim \infty 2n = \infty$. Or is it $\frac {2n}n = 2$ so $\lim_{n\to 0}\frac {2n}n=\lim 2 = 2$.  They can't all be right.  You can't separate limits that way so the first two are wrong.

Comment: then what steps I have to take to discuss its convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st $(a^n+b^n)^{1/n}=b[[1+(\frac{a}{b})^n]^{(\frac{b}{a})^n}]^{(\frac{a}{b})^n\frac{1}{n}}\to b e^0=b$

2nd $\qquad b\le (a^n+b^n)^{1/n}\le b\cdot 2^{1/n}$ so by the Squeezing Theorem ...

Comment: I have to discuss the convergence of a sequence, how to show that?